# Closing/reopening questions

Tags: discussion, closed-questions, vote-to-close

I've been a user of Stack Exchange for a while now.  I usually see questions closed by vote, which gives the question-asker the ability to give reasons not to close the question (things the close-voters might not have thought of or seen).  However, I recently had a question closed by one moderator, not allowing me discussion on why it shouldn't be closed.  In this case, is there a course of action such that I can lobby for my question to be opened again?

( [This question](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/16251/should-site-title-be-before-or-after-page-title) is what I was talking about )

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The reason why it was closed by a single moderator is this site currently only has eleven users who can cast close votes and three of those eleven are moderators. This means it's difficult to get one or two close votes much less five to close a question. As a result many of the questions here are closed by a single moderator.

This doesn't mean you cannot lobby to have your question reopened. If through discussion it is determined that the question should be reopened, myself or another moderator will be very happy to do so.

I'm not sure if the discussion should be held in meta (here) or as comments of the original question. I think here is appropriate but if I am wrong I'm sure someone will let us know. So if you would like to start a new question explaining why you would like to see the question reopened I say go for it and let's figure it out as a community.

Comment: Right-o.  I've asked here: http://meta.webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/514/lobbying-for-reopening