# Lobbying For Reopening

Tags: discussion, closed-questions

Per [this question](https://webmasters.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/512/closing-reopening-questions),  this is a lobby to reopen the question [Should Site Title be Before or After Page Title?](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/16251/should-site-title-be-before-or-after-page-title) on webmasters.se.

I do not see the question as a duplicate of the other, because the referenced question discusses only keywords in the title and purely in SEO terms.  I was looking more for a possible semantic reason (as well as any SEO benefits) and was specifically aiming for answers related to the relationship between sites and pages.

Answer (score 2):

Reopened as requested; you may want this question migrated to the [User Interface/User Experience StackExchange](https://ux.stackexchange.com/) site to get answers from UI/UX professionals (there are no existing duplicates on the UI/UX site from the searches I tried).

Answer (score 2):

IMO I think this is an OK question on webmasters.

I can see where it might be considered a tiny bit bikeshed (chocolate or vanilla?) but it is well asked and certainly relevant to the average webmaster.

Comment: Isn't the question a duplicate of http://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/6556/does-the-order-of-keywords-matter-in-a-page-title ?

Comment: @disgruntled eh, not exactly; one is about `site - title`, the other is about general order of keywords within `title`.